# Git is thinking a @(Ctrl+Alt+2) is a R

Tags: git, config

I was looking to set up my git, but I can't put an `@` in my email, whenever I try it puts me an `R` instead of the `@`. My shortcut to `@` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: What keyboard language are you using?

Comment: You'll need to give details about your environment, OS, terminal, etc. Pretend git works fine for most people.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi I don't really found anything about "Keyboard Language" but I found Key board layout is it the same? If it is the same thing, I am using QWERTY.

Comment: qwerty layout is different for many languages. I'm using ISO UK for instance which uses qwerty. I have £ as shift+3, but the ANSI layout has # instead.

Comment: Also _how_ are you setting up git?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Hi I actually don't know that like most of the people, so I searched for it in my computer my OS is windows (Windows 10 Home) my terminal is... command line, I don't know what's an environment isn't it the same as OS? And it's hard to answer more because I can't guess what "etc" contains, so I can search for it (I am not much of a techie guy ok...? I just jumped into a python tutorial and a git one.) sorry for this long text...

Comment: @evolutionxbox I just downloaded it and follow the installer... (using all the predefinitions because they sounded good...)

Comment: So this config is in a ui window? Or in the command prompt?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi I Am using Portuguese QWERTY according to windows

Comment: Command prompt i already installed it i has trying to use  `$ git config --global user.name "EXAMPLE"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

Comment: What about AltGr + 2 instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i don't knowed about that... i will try

Comment: @evolutionxbox It worked THANKS :D ( i don't know how stack overflow works at all...  do i need to check the question as solved?)

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout) the <kbd>@</kbd> can be accessed using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> on the Portuguese ISO Qwerty layout.

[image: Portuguese keyboard layout]

Comment: `print("Bye World")`